# qtip doesn't format into bold?

Tags: qtip2

I have this simple well-formed html like

```
<span><p><b>User:&nbsp;</b>USERNAME<br><strong>Date:&nbsp;</strong>from&nbsp;28-04-2022 08:00:00&nbsp;to&nbsp;28-04-2022 16:00:00<br><strong></p></span>
```

and I passed to qtip but once I show the tip I see it doesn't apply bold formatting...indeed saving into a normal html file it works well.... shall I have to add some particular option?

In the specific with this javascript :

```
$(info.el).qtip({ 
    content: { text: $.ajax({url:"http://"+window.location.host+"/...../my.php?action=load_eventdetails&ID="+info.event.id, async:false}).responseText }, 
    position: { target: 'mouse', effect: false, viewport: .... , adjust: { x: 10, y: 10, method: 'flipinvert' } }, 
});
```

I call a php to obtain an html string:

```
<html><body><p><span><b>User:&nbsp;</b>Name Surname<br><b>Date:&nbsp;</b>from&nbsp;04-03-2016 08:00:00&nbsp;to&nbsp;04-03-2016 16:00:00<br><b>Room:&nbsp;</b>Room 1&nbsp;()<br><b>Placement:&nbsp;</b><br><b>Services:</b><br><ol style='list-style-type: circle'><li style='font-size: 13px'>n&deg;&nbsp;1&nbsp;-&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</li><li style='font-size: 13px'>n&deg;&nbsp;6&nbsp;-&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</li><li style='font-size: 13px'>n&deg;&nbsp;1&nbsp;-&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</li><li style='font-size: 13px'>n&deg;&nbsp;1&nbsp;-&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</li><li style='font-size: 13px'>n&deg;&nbsp;6&nbsp;-&nbsp;Lorem Ipsum</li></ol><div style='font-size: 13px;margin-bottom: 1px'><div style='float:left'><b>Price:</b></div><div style='float:right'>&euro;&nbsp;XX,00</div></div><br><div style='font-size: 13px;margin-bottom: 5px'><div style='float:left'><b>Lorem Ipsum:</b></div><div style='float:right'>&euro;&nbsp;XX.00</div></div><br><div style='font-size: 13px;margin-bottom: 5px'><div style='float:left'><b>Lorem Ipsum:</b></div><div style='float:right'>&euro;&nbsp;XX.00</div></div><br><div style='font-size: 13px;margin-bottom: 1px'><div style='float:left'><b>Lorem Ipsum:</b></div><div style='float:right'>&euro;&nbsp;XX,XX</div></div><br> <div style="font-size: 13px;margin-bottom: 1px"><div style="float:left"><img src=".../images/myimg.png" />&nbsp;<b>STATUS</b></div></div> </span></p></body></html>
```

Where with a simple html file I get correctly the result with bold formatting where expected...
Thanks in advance!
Cheers! :-)

Comment: Include your code in your question, and also tag the language you are using (i.e. JavaScript.)

Comment: Note also that this is not a well formed HTML fragment. You have an unclosed `<strong>` element, and are placing a block element `<p>` inside an inline element `<span>`

Comment: Hello @miken32 , I updated the post with the sample I am using... (I inverted span and p tags after your notice but it doesn't change)....

Comment: What does the second block of HTML have to do with the first? Which is being used in your code? You are still putting block level elements inside your `<span>` in the second.